# How to read exceptions(error log) in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to find way how to read issues explanations at Unity console?
For example:
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () (at <"d3b66f0ad4e34a55b6ef91ab84878193">:0)

In this exception(error) I see next containers:

1. UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke ()
2. (at <"d3b66f0ad4e34a55b6ef91ab84878193">:0)

Sometimes it can be more or different containers for other errors.
But I can't find where I can read the expressions.

I mean, I want to know what is this? (at <"d3b66f0ad4e34a55b6ef91ab84878193">:0)
I tried to search in memory addreses structure, UID, GUID and so on. but nothing was like this note - (at <"d3b66f0ad4e34a55b6ef91ab84878193">:0)

Important! Chars and nums may be another. It's not matter.

"" - this symbol is abscent. Typed just for view.

Comment: https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000292166-Symbolicate-Android-crash ?

Comment: Thank you, @Morion , but it's not tell about what is this. And there is not type of memory address, that I know. Cause usually memory addres seems like "0000d248"  or "0000d248 : 1249s789".
I need explanation for each part of exception message.

Maybe we can search in Unity library, but I tried and can't find any similar =(

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @MickyD , I wanna to know where and which problem I have. To understand errors I want to know how work built-in error logger.